# Keydown event doesn't fire on an embedded form in firemonkey after overriding the keydown event on the embedded form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a firemonkey application that opens forms that are embedded into controls on the main form.  I am trying to use the keydown event on the embedded form but the event doesn't fire.  Other posts recommend overriding the keydown event on the form, but this only works when it's done on the main form, even when overridden the event is never triggered on the embedded form.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll find that the main form takes responsibility for keyboard handling, and events are passed down through the parent/child relationships to the controls in such a way that the sub-form never sees them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be another way around, such as using the controls OnKeyDown events, or getting your main form to manually pass on KeyDown stuff to the child form.

Comment: I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut to trigger an onclick event for a button.  For Example CTRL+S to initiate a "Save" button click.  Since the child forms are opened in tabs, I think I'll use the event on the main form and then get the form from active tab to call the onclick event.  I was hoping to have the child form register the button click as there can be a lot of open forms in this application.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the main forms' OnKeyDown event to scan child controls for a TForm descendant and resend the "onkeydown" to the contained form.

Should be a simple routine - if you put it into a shared unit you could use it in all forms to ensure keypresses propagate to contained forms.